# Why my .env variables are not working in Parcel?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, parcel

I'm trying to use env variables in Parcel `parcel-bundler version 1.12.4` but it returns undefined. Here is my [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt8cB.png). As you can see the `.env` file is in the same folder as the `package.json` file.

This is the variable I'm using `API_KEY=myapikey` and I'm trying to console log it from my index.js file like this `console.log(process.env.API_KEY)`.

I just want to know if I'm doing something wrong or if need to open an issue.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I fixed it by deleting the `.cache` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `npm i dotenv` package

Add the following command to `index.js` file:
`require('dotenv').config()`

this imports your credentials from .env package and now you can access and use it in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that `dotenv` is an option for this, but I wanted to do it directly with parcel. I think I'm gonna end up using `dotenv` tho. https://parceljs.org/env.html here's the documentation. I found an issue with the same problem but the person with the problem didn't have the `.env` file in the root folder. So it didn't helped a lot.

Comment: How did you fix it? Installing dotenv manually or did you figure out how to make it work by default with parcel?

Comment: @tamj0rd2 I just deleted the `.cache` folder and restarted the server, I didn't use the dotenv library